# How to disable DEBUG message and display only INFO message in tomcat catalina.out file using log4j

Tags: debugging, message

09:54:48.977 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#1'
09:54:48.978 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#2'
09:54:49.453 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#2'
09:54:49.454 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#3'
09:54:49.696 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#3'
09:54:49.696 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#4'
09:54:50.054 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#4'
09:54:50.055 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#5'
09:54:50.417 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#5'
09:54:50.418 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#6'
09:54:51.135 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#6'
09:54:51.136 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#7'
09:54:51.853 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#7'
09:54:51.853 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#8'
09:54:54.716 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#8'
09:54:54.831 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0'
09:54:55.370 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0'
09:54:55.370 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0'
09:54:55.370 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0'
09:54:55.370 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0'
09:54:55.487 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
10:06:27.851 [http-nio-8081-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Written [{"data":{"code":success,"message":{"title":"Title“}}

Answer (score 0):

To filter out some packages and leave others at debug add loggers. Assuming you are using logback and spring, in your logback-spring.xml:

```
...
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%marker - ${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka.clients" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.beans" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.core.env" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="INFO"/>
...
```

will get rid of a lot of the spring noise. Choose whichever packages you wish to change the level of.

Interestingly, it is possible to use the short forms shown in the log with one word of caution, the logger will only match the string exactly. e.g.

```
<logger name="o.e.j.util" level="INFO"/>
```

will change the logging level of `o.e.j.util` and any classes that are logged with that string as the start of the full class namespace to INFO, but it will not change the logging level of `org.eclipse.jetty.util` or `o.e.jetty.util` as these are essentially different strings. If you want to change the logging level of all classes in the `org.eclipse.jetty.util` package you need to use the full package name:

```
 <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util" level="INFO"/>
```

Hope that makes sense?